# How to configure UTF-8 in Spring Boot 2 with Spring MVC & Security, Jasig CAS and JSP views?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-security, cas

I'm trying to configure a simple Spring Boot application with CAS authentication using Spring Security, views are all JSPs and rendered using Spring MVC. However, I ran into a character encoding issue when testing the secured view. Non-ASCII characters seem to be incorrectly displayed (e.g. Ĺˇ instead of š, Ăˇ instead of á etc.).

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.4 and CAS client core 3.6.1. The application is built with Maven (with custom parent) and deployed to a full Tomcat 9.0.30 instance (default configuration) as a WAR file.

So far I have tried:

1. Explicitly forcing HTTP UTF-8 encoding in *application.properties*
2. Registering a `CharacterEncodingFilter` using `FilterRegistrationBean`
3. Using `addFilterBefore` in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (several variations with different filters as the `beforeFilter` parameter)
4. Adding a `CharacterEncodingFilter` bean with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` to the `SpringBootServletInitializer` (annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` as this is my entry point)
5. Extending `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` and overriding `beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain`
6. Adding a `FilterRegistrationBean`, configuring the filter in it and setting the order to a very low number
7. Registering my own filter where I explicitly set request and response encoding to UTF-8
8. Overriding `onStartup` in `SpringBootServletInitializer` and adding the filter directly to the servlet context

The strings in question are being obtained using Spring Security taglib as `<security:authentication property="principal.firstName"/>`. The text is correctly encoded if logged using SLF4J. I'd like to avoid using a *web.xml* deployment descriptor since this has been a very Spring Bootish application so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unsuccessfully attempting to fix this using multiple additional approaches, my colleague suggested to have a look if there is anything from CAS where character encoding can be set.

Turns out a `Cas30ServiceTicketValidator` bean was the offender as it somehow managed to override settings from all the approaches listed in the question (and several more). This is the version that ended up working:

```
@Bean
public TicketValidator ticketValidator() {
    Cas30ServiceTicketValidator validator = new Cas30ServiceTicketValidator("https://example.com/cas");
    validator.setEncoding("UTF-8"); //This had to be added
    return validator;
}
```

No additional changes were required after this, the rest was configured more or less according to [Baeldung's Spring Security CAS SSO tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cas-sso).